# pointers/structures

Tags: c, structure

I would like to ask question regarding pointers. I dont know what to do here, I have a method in the main that is calling a method outside the main, and I need to use pointers.Basically this is the rough draft of it: Thanks!

```
 char *book[] = { "x", "y", "z",};
 int number[] = { 1, 2, 3};

 struct data{ char *bookname; int booknumber;};

 struct data *list[3];

  my_method(char *x, int y, int *z)
 {


   //creating a new struct 
   list[(*z)++] = (struct data*) malloc( sizeof(struct data) );

   //assigning arguments
   list[(*z)++]->bookname = x;
   list[(*z)++]->booknumber = y;

   (*z)++;
 }

 int main()
 {
   int nextValue = 0;

   my_method(book[nextValue], book[nextValue], &nextValue);

   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
     function(book[i], number[i]);

     printf("name: %c number: %d", list[i]->bookname, list[i]->booknumber);
   }
  }
```

Comment: If you call it with `&nextValue`, the declaration should be `int nextValue = 0;`, for an `int`, not an `int*`.

Comment: Also take out the `static void` in main.

Comment: 1) Is this homework? 2) Why do you need to use pointers? 3) What are the functions you want to call supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Could you post the complete code, if it is not too large? Or reduce it to the basic problem and post that?  What you have looks ok. Is there actually a probleM? If so, what?

Comment: calling my_method is done in wrong way. "static void" is unnecessary.

Comment: @Daniel, that was my first guess, since I;m actually passing the value, but I am still getting a compiler error on my method in main

Comment: @JackMorton As PaulR said, the `static void` in `main` doesn't belong there. That's not valid C.

Comment: @Jack Mortan, please post your compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the wrong arguments to your method. Try changing the following line:

```
my_method(book[nextValue], number[nextValue], &nextValue);
```

In addition, in your method you seem to be incrementing z four times, which I doubt is the behavior you want.  You should only increment it once at the end, like the following:

```
//creating a new struct 
list[*z] = (struct data*) malloc( sizeof(struct data) );

//assigning arguments
list[*z]->bookname = x;
list[*z]->booknumber = y;

(*z)++;
```

Comment: It worked partially, Thanks a lot s0vereignT! Now, I know I;m on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Simply removed unnecessary static void.

```
 //declaration of method outside the main 
  void my_method(............,int *nextValue)
  {
  //................................//
  //..............................//


  //then increment the pointer
  (*nextValue)++;
  }//my_method

  int main()
  {

   int nextValue = 0;

  //Removed static void
  my_method(............, &nextValue);
  //........................................//
  }//main
```